# Forumla to determine if something arrives on time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to build a formula in the "on time" column below. It must do the following.

1. if available date cell has data then 
       if available date is <= to expected date "yes" otherwise "no"
2. if available date cell is blank then 
       if expected date < current day "no" otherwise leave cell blank

The current day column uses the today() function. If it easier to add that to the formula that is fine.

Expected Date | Current Day |  Available Date |  On Time

`=IF(C2<>"",IF(AND(C2<=A2,A2<B2),"Yes","No"),"")`

Currently I have this formula. However this does not work because of the location of the c<>"" section. I've tried a few things but that is probably as close as I have gotten.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`=IF(C2<>"",IF(C2<=A2,"Yes","No"),IF(A2<B2,"No",""))`